# How can I split a single, very long string into separate columns and rows delimited by commas and semicolons in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, row

I'm trying to split a single very long string into a seperate colomns and rows.
The columns need to be delimited with the "," symbol and the rows are delimmited witht he ";" symbol.

Example of data that's stored in the Sql table in as datatype Nvarchar(max)

Containing 11 columns, and hundreds of rows. `PARSENAME` does not appear to work because of limitations and how it likes to use full stops which is a problem because there are GPS co-ordinates in the data.

Split string does work to move the data into a new row though but I was getting a lot of `NULL`s because of parse name limitation. Please advise... I've googled and chatgpted this for like a day with no great results.

Data example First 5 rows but could be up to thousands of rows.

```
"Tag No,Tag2 No,Location ID,Log Length,Log Diameter,Log Thick Diameter,Volume,Team ID,Scan DateTime,Checker ID,LogType ID,Latitude,Longitude,Altitude,HCS No;67599715,0,155341,330,17,0,0.0901491,144,2022-11-16 13:59:12.208,1008,HEWSAW,0,0,0,83493;67599716,0,155341,330,15,0,0.0718509,144,2022-11-16 13:59:16.997,1008,HEWSAW,0,0,0,83493;67599717,0,155341,330,16,0,0.0807408,144,2022-11-16 13:59:20.733,1008,HEWSAW,0,0,0,83493;67599718,0,155341,330,18,0,0.100076,144,2022-11-16 13:59:23.618,1008,HEWSAW,0,0,0,83493;67599719,0,155341,330,17,0,0.0901491,144,2022-11-16 13:59:26.736,1008,HEWSAW,0,0,0,83493;67599720,0,155341,330,15,0,0.0718509,144,2022-11-16 13:59:29.718,1008,HEWSAW,0,0,0,83493;67599721,0,155341,330,16,0,0.0807408,144,2022-11-16 13:59:33.809,1008,HEWSAW,0,0,0,83493;67599722,0,155341,330,17,0,0.0901491,144,2022-11-16 13:59:38.118,1008,HEWSAW,0,0,0,83493;67599723,0,155341,330,15,0,0.0718509,144,2022-11-16 13:59:41.346,1008,HEWSAW,0,0,0,83493;"
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE #test124 (
  LoadedTag1 varchar(15),
  LoadCheckerID VARCHAR(50),
  LoadedAt varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO #test124 (LoadedTag1, LoadCheckerID, LoadedAt)
SELECT
 PARSENAME(REPLACE(VALUE, ',', '.'), 11) AS LoadedTag1,
  PARSENAME(REPLACE(VALUE, ',', '.'), 2) AS LoadCheckerID,
 PARSENAME(REPLACE(VALUE, ',', '.'), 1) AS LoadedAt
FROM STRING_SPLIT(("Pauls Data"), ';');


select * from #test124
drop table #test124
```

Then I tried this approach and now all I have is one column, where I want row and column

```sql
CREATE TABLE Testdata
(
    TagNo Int,
    Tag2No int, 
    LocationID nvarchar (50),
    LogLength int,
    LogDiameter int, 
    LogThickDiameter int,
    Volume float,
    TeamID id,
    ScanDateTime datetime,
    CheckerID nvarchar (50),
    LogTypeID nvarchar(50),
    Latitude float,
    Longitude float, 
    Altitude float
   
);
 
 String VARCHAR(MAX) = (select LogString from syncbuffer where id = '522900')



WITH tmp(TagNo,
Tag2No,
LocationID,
LogLength,
LogDiameter,
LogThickDiameter,
Volume,
TeamID,
ScanDateTime,
CheckerID,
LogTypeID,
Latitude,
Longitude,
Altitude, DataItem, String) AS
(
    SELECT
        TagNo,
Tag2No,
LocationID,
LogLength,
LogDiameter,
LogThickDiameter,
Volume,
TeamID,
ScanDateTime,
CheckerID,
LogTypeID,
Latitude,
Longitude
Altitude,
        LEFT(String, CHARINDEX(',', String + ',') - 1),
        STUFF(String, 1, CHARINDEX(',', String + ','), '')
    FROM Testdata
    UNION all

    SELECT
             TagNo,
Tag2No,
LocationID,
LogLength,
LogDiameter,
LogThickDiameter,
Volume,
TeamID,
ScanDateTime,
CheckerID,
LogTypeID,
Latitude,
Longitude
Altitude,
        LEFT(String, CHARINDEX(',', String + ',') - 1),
        STUFF(String, 1, CHARINDEX(',', String + ','), '')
    FROM tmp
    WHERE
        String > ''
)
SELECT
         TagNo,
Tag2No,
LocationID,
LogLength,
LogDiameter,
LogThickDiameter,
Volume,
TeamID,
ScanDateTime,
CheckerID,
LogTypeID,
Latitude,
Longitude
Altitude
FROM tmp
ORDER BY SomeID;
-- OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
-- normally recursion is limited to 100. If you know you have very long
-- strings, uncomment the option
```

Comment: This is a task for your ETL layer, not the  SQL layer. In what ever process is `INSERT`ing the data is should be splitting the data into the needed columns and inserting them into the relevant columns in the table.

Comment: Honestly... we have a number of scanners that dump this data into the table like this. I heard what your saying about the database design, etc,etc but this doesn't help me now.

Comment: I didn't say anything about the design, I'm saying that the process to split this isn't a SQL task; do the splitting before the data ever gets to the database.

Comment: sorry, this is data that is already sitting in the database as varchar(max) string. I can call the data out of the database with a select and insert it into some or other function. the dataset comes from a legacy database and that's just how it was stored back then.

Comment: Then you probably want to use a different tool to extract the data and then re-insert it into the database. The above *looks* like a bit of a malformed CSV format; if you remove those quotes, then it would be consumable as one (using semicolons (`;`) as a row delimiter, rather than (CR)LF). Powershell, as an example, can easily consume CSV files.

Comment: Whats really happing is that the original developer uses C# app to extract this data and put it into the another table. The C# app sometimes fails and we loose data. I want to create a script to compare the raw data against the processed data. The script will only run at midnight and will only update a table that will advise me which sets of raw data need to be reprocessed. or at least that's my intention.  I do not have access to the original C# apps code.

Comment: Do you use sql server 2022 or some earlier version? it's relevant cause STRING_SPLIT has a ordinal argument in later version which might help you

Comment: Your sample table also appears to be missing a column. Your sample CSV-like data has a column "HSCNo" but that is omitted in your table `Testdata`'s definition. Is that intentional?

Comment: This data, however, is easily inserted into a table (with the `HSCNo` column) [using `BULK INSERT`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foi0d.png) if you export the data to a text file.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Taka peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64140091/c-sharp-unpivot-columns-in-rows/64144070#64144070

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, LogString NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tbl (LogString) VALUES
(N'Tag No,Tag2 No,Location ID,Log Length,Log Diameter,Log Thick Diameter,Volume,Team ID,Scan DateTime,Checker ID,LogType ID,Latitude,Longitude,Altitude,HCS No;67599715,0,155341,330,17,0,0.0901491,144,2022-11-16 13:59:12.208,1008,HEWSAW,0,0,0,83493;67599716,0,155341,330,15,0,0.0718509,144,2022-11-16 13:59:16.997,1008,HEWSAW,0,0,0,83493;67599717,0,155341,330,16,0,0.0807408,144,2022-11-16 13:59:20.733,1008,HEWSAW,0,0,0,83493;67599718,0,155341,330,18,0,0.100076,144,2022-11-16 13:59:23.618,1008,HEWSAW,0,0,0,83493;67599719,0,155341,330,17,0,0.0901491,144,2022-11-16 13:59:26.736,1008,HEWSAW,0,0,0,83493;67599720,0,155341,330,15,0,0.0718509,144,2022-11-16 13:59:29.718,1008,HEWSAW,0,0,0,83493;67599721,0,155341,330,16,0,0.0807408,144,2022-11-16 13:59:33.809,1008,HEWSAW,0,0,0,83493;67599722,0,155341,330,17,0,0.0901491,144,2022-11-16 13:59:38.118,1008,HEWSAW,0,0,0,83493;67599723,0,155341,330,15,0,0.0718509,144,2022-11-16 13:59:41.346,1008,HEWSAW,0,0,0,83493;');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID
    , TagNo = JSON_VALUE(j,'$[0]')
    , Tag2No = JSON_VALUE(j,'$[1]')
    , LocationID = JSON_VALUE(j,'$[2]')
    , LogLength = JSON_VALUE(j,'$[3]')
    ...
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(TRIM(';' FROM LogString), ';')
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT '["' + REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(value, 'json'), ',', '","') + '"]') AS t1(j)
WHERE value NOT LIKE 'Tag%';
```

**Output**

| ID | TagNo | Tag2No | LocationID | LogLength |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 67599715 | 0 | 155341 | 330 |
| 1 | 67599716 | 0 | 155341 | 330 |
| 1 | 67599717 | 0 | 155341 | 330 |
| 1 | 67599718 | 0 | 155341 | 330 |
| 1 | 67599719 | 0 | 155341 | 330 |
| 1 | 67599720 | 0 | 155341 | 330 |
| 1 | 67599721 | 0 | 155341 | 330 |
| 1 | 67599722 | 0 | 155341 | 330 |
| 1 | 67599723 | 0 | 155341 | 330 |